# MongoDb Script Timing Out / Not Logging Iteration

Tags: mongodb

I am running this script:

```
db.parts.find( { Barcodes: { $exists: true, $ne: null, $not: {$size: 0} } })
    .forEach(function (doc) {
        doc.Barcodes.forEach(function (barcode) {
            barcode.ValueLc = barcode.Value.toLowerCase(); 
        });
        db.parts.save(doc);
    });
```

The goal is to add a new field to the "Barcodes" array of "Barcode" objects. This new field is a lowercase of an existing field. I believe I am doing everything correctly, but I need to update 1.5 million records. Last time this ran for an hour and only updated 30,000 items. Worst of all, it returned a list of "Updated one record" entries without giving me a number of how many records it updated todal.

Is there any way I can get that number? I don't see a way to log each iteration in Robomongo (print seems to affect output?).

So main question is, how do I log how many results are updated? You know, this type of deal:

```
var i = 0;
foreach(whatever){i++;}
console.log(i); //at the end of the .forEach loop
```

Secondary question (not essential) is how I can keep it from timing out? (I don't actually expect there to be an answer to this part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to do it through [`Bulk`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/). First of all, add `ValueLc` field to subdocument through [`.map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/), then start bulk operation, and update the document through `bulk.find.update` operation, find by `_id` and update the `Barcodes` subdocument array.

```
> var c = db.parts.find(
              {Barcodes: {$exists: true, $ne: null, $not: {$size: 0}}}
          ).map(function(doc){ 
                      doc.Barcodes.forEach(function(barcode){
                               barcode.ValueLc= barcode.Value.toLowerCase();
                      }); 
                      return doc;
      });
> var bulk = db.parts.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
> c.forEach(function(ret){
              bulk.find({_id: ret._id})
                  .update({$set: {Barcodes: ret.Barcodes}});
      }); 
  bulk.execute();
```

And the result shows as bellow.

```
BulkWriteResult({
        "writeErrors" : [ ],
        "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nMatched" : 1,
        "nModified" : 1,
        "nRemoved" : 0,
        "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

BTW, there is one `timeout` in the [`bulk.execute()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.execute/#Bulk.execute), however, **wtimeout** of 5000 milliseconds such that the method returns after the writes propagate to a majority of the voting replica set members or the method times out after 5 seconds.

Comment: Worked perfectly, really appreciate it. For people looking at this later, if you are using robomongo, you need to update to 0.9.0 or later to run this. Or just run it from console.